# Probability of an image containing a specific object, by combining the results of multiple dependent tests

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, naive-bayes, independence, object-detection

I am trying to assign to images the probability of them containing a metal building. The images can contain either metal buildings, non-metal buildings or no building.

Let $B$ be the event that an image contains a building, and $M$ be the event that an image contains a metal building.

I have a test $T_B$ which tells me if an image contains a building or not, and other tests $T_{Mi}$ which tell me if an image contains a *metal* building or not. I have empirically estimated the sensitivity, specificity of each test and the prevalence of metal buildings and buildings.

Given the result of $T_B$, I can determine $P(B \mid T_B)$ by using the test's $PPV$ or $(1 - NPV)$.

By following the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/560820/calculate-probablity-of-covid-19-infection-from-2-positive-and-1-negative-tests?rq=1), I derived a formula to combine the $T_{Mi}$ test results and obtain $P(M \mid T_M)$ where $T_M$ is the set of metal building-related test results.

I am then multiplying the two probabilities together to score the images. This works quite well in practice, with metal building images at the top, and those with no building at the bottom.

I have tried using only $P(M \mid T_M)$ to score the images but since the absence of a building is not penalized, a lot of images with buildings end up ranking as low as those without buildings. It's important that images with buildings rank higher than those without, as we're planning to manually go through the results in descending score order and want to maximize the number of metal buildings we find.

After trying to write it out, I realized I was doing something like
$$
P(M \cap B \mid T_M \cap T_B) = P(M \mid T_M) * P(B \mid T_B)
$$
which, as far as I can tell, is completely wrong.

In reality, we have dependence between $M$ and $B$, and therefore also between $T_M$ and $T_B$.
$$
P(M \cap B) = P(M \mid B) * P(B)
$$

So a few questions:

- How can I write out the equation for $P(M \cap B \mid T_M \cap T_B)$ ?
- Is my approach completely hopeless mathematically? I thought that it made sense intuitively, and works well in practice, can I simply call it a 'score' instead of a probability and move on?
- Does someone know any resources/other examples of similar situations? What do people do in practice?

Thank you